# Factors for websites enjoying solely on organic searches

Tags: google, domains, google-search-console, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

What factors should we consider, when building an Q'n'A website which is solely based on organic searches?

Note: I am gathering all information about starting a website driven solely on organic searches.

**Even a minute detail here will help me a lot.**

Please enlighten me.

Thanks :)

Comment: No website is 'driven solely on organic searches'. Every website will see traffic from repeat visitors and shared links, even if those sources are small. The best thing you can do to maximise search traffic is to follow the advice in the post above to build a site that ranks well.

Answer (score 0):

Your website should have good answer avoiding spamming comment.

website should have user interaction things like rating, liking, sharing

website should be search engine friendly url.

website should have openid login features

connect should be crawlable to search engines.

Good admin panel to control spamming

Good internal search features so that people may get proper questions/answer.

website MUST be open soon and userfriendly